# list.Clear() vs new List<>() - ASP.NET Core - Entity Framework Core - Lazy loading

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

After some time investigating why my navigation property gets filled up again with the entities that I just removed (using entity.NavigationPropertiesCollection = new List<>()), I realised that with entity.NavigationPropertiesCollection.Clear() everything works fine. My question is why does Entity Framework Core load the navigation properties again after I have reinitialized the navigation property collection and why with entity.NavigationPropertiesCollection.Clear() everything works fine? (removes them as expected)

Prerequisite nuget packages: 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Prerequisite code:

```
public class FooChildEntity
 {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
 }
public class FooParentEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FooChildEntity> FooChildEntities { get; set; }
}

internal class FooDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=fooDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    public DbSet<FooParentEntity> FooParentEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Code to reproduce:

First run this code:

```
     FooParentEntity fooParentEntityInput = new FooParentEntity
        {
            Title = "cool title",
            FooChildEntities = new List<FooChildEntity>
            {
                new FooChildEntity
                {
                    Name = "FirstChild"
                },
                new FooChildEntity
                {
                    Name="SecondChild"
                }
            }
        };

        FooDbContext fooDbContext = new FooDbContext();
        fooDbContext.FooParentEntities.Add(fooParentEntityInput);

        fooDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

and delete it or comment it out.

After that the following code using breakpoints as in the screenshots

```
FooDbContext fooDbContext = new FooDbContext();

FooParentEntity fooParentEntityDb = fooDbContext.FooParentEntities.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
fooParentEntityDb.FooChildEntities = new List<FooChildEntity>();
fooParentEntityDb.FooChildEntities.Add(new FooChildEntity { Name = "ThirdChild" });
```

> Here the bug appears: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ1j0.png
>
> However if
>   using multiple breakpoints while debugging like in the screenshots:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/naCxJ.png
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky7K5.png
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/iziRr.png
>
> Everything works out perfectly.

Comment: We'll need to see the code for the entity definition and actual usage to be certain.  As your question is phrased now there would be a lot of wild guessing.  Also: welcome to stack overflow!